# How to recover from EAGAIN error on a non-blocking socket.send?

Tags: sockets, micropython

I'm writing a simple script for LoPy4 module. The scrip is supposed to send a PING message at an interval of X. I'm doing this using socket.send() with a non-blocking socket, but every once in a while I get `EAGAIN` error.

Comparing the size of the data that supposed to be sent and the return value of the `send()` method shows that everything was sent. So, I guess the buffer supposed to be empty, and still, I get this error which takes approx 10 sec to recover (or restarting the LoPy).

How can I recover (or avoid) from this error skipping just one interval

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.setblocking(False)
while True:

  try:
        bytes = s.send(MY_DATA)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.args[0] == 11:
            print('EAGAIN error occurred, skipping')
            continue
  time.sleep(INTERVAL)
```

Comment: What happens when you move the socket creation outside the loop?

Comment: `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` on a non-blocking send means the socket is not writable, ie the *peer*'s inbound buffer is full and not accepting more data at that moment. Simply move on and retry the same send again at a later time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's what I thought, but it takes approx 10 sec, to recover, seems very long to me. Additionally, I'm not sending it to a peer, just broadcasting.

Comment: @RCB since you are sending in a tight loop, it is also possible that you are sending data faster than the OS can actually send it, so your socket's send buffer is filling up

Comment: @RemyLebeau How can I query it? Or clear/flush the buffer? What do you think the minimal working rate should be? Currently, I'm trying ~32bytes/sec (forgot to add the sleep to the question) it doesn't seem too fast to me.

Comment: @RCB most socket APIs have access to `select()` or `(e)poll()` to query a socket for readability/writability, but Python's `socket` doesn't have that. And you can't flush a socket. Once outbound data is in the kernel, it is out of your hands.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Don't you think that if I try to send 32Bytes/sec it shouldn't be too fast?

Comment: @RCB perhaps. On the other hand, I have no idea how `AF_LORA` actually works at the transport level (never heard of it before). And, your loop is skipping the `sleep()` when `EAGAIN` occurs.